# Can anyone tell me how to checking if Pytorch model exists, and if it does, delete it and replace it with a new one?

Tags: python, pytorch

So I save a lot of torch models for training and with different batchsize and epochs, and the models are saves with strings of epoch and batchsize. Basically I sometimes change some layers hyperparamters and some augmentation to check the prediction results, but if the torch model is there, I want to delete it and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Just use `torch.save` with the same path/name. It will override the old model save.

Comment: I thought It will use the previous grads and update them.
Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: No, it just writes down all your current parameters into a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is simply saving a model with the same name, essentially overwriting the existing one. This is equivalent to checking if it exists, deleting and then saving.

If you want to explicitly check if it exists, you can do that easily with `os.`

```
import os
if os.path.exists('path/to/model.pth'):  # checking if there is a file with this name
    os.remove('path/to/model.pth')  # deleting the file
    torch.save(model, 'path/to/model.pth')  # saving a new model with the same name
```

Comment: I made a folder and then directly deleted the folder if the model is present.
But thanks , this also works.